# May I know what is the expected value of the second ball being taken, and the expected value of the product?

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve this problem:
'In a bag n balls numbered 1 ,2,....,n, and each ball is equally likely to be taken. A ball is taken out of the bag. The number on the ball is noted and the ball is not replaced int he bag. Another ball is taken out of the bag and the number on this ball is noted. What is the expected value of the number of the second ball being taken out?'
So, my thought is that:
If the second ball is one, the probability would be:
$$\frac{n-1}{n} \times \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}$$
This is because I think that in order to have number 1 in the second ball, we would have to not take the number '1' at the first ball, and take the number '1' at the second ball. So, due to the fact that each number would have the same probability being taken out, the expected value of the number of the second ball would be:
$$\frac{n+1}{2}$$
May I know why I am wrong? Thank you very much users.

Update:
Thank you very much users. So, the thing that I don't understand is that why isn't the expected value of the product of the two balls $$\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$$

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Do we know what the set of numbers in the bag is?  If the values are known then each draw has the same expected value.

Comment: I am sorry, I will amend the question, I found that I have some information missed

Comment: Right.  As I said, under that assumption each draw has the same expectation (since any of the given values is equally likely to be drawn in that turn).  So the answer is indeed $\frac {n+1}2$, though I can not really follow your argument for that.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much. May I know what is the expected value of the product of the number on the two balls. Would it be $\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$?

Comment: No, it is not that, because the two draws are not independent.  for this one I see no easier way than to evaluate the sum directly (it's not all that difficult).

Comment: Why do you think you're wrong? The answer is correct. You just have to show your reasoning more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think of the expected value of the second ball is to see you do nothing with the number on the first, so imagine drawing one ball, then a second, then swap them and look at the number on the (now) second ball.  It is the first ball drawn, which has an expected value of $\frac {n+1}2$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct. The working should be clearer.

Let $k$ be any integer in the range $[1,n]$.

The ball with value $k$ will be drawn on the second turn if and only if a ball of value other than $k$ is drawn on the first turn *and* the ball with value $k$ is drawn on the second turn.

If we let $p(k)$ be the probability of the ball labelled $k$ being drawn on the second turn, then $\displaystyle p(k) = \frac{n-1}n \cdot \frac 1{n-1} = \frac 1n$, which is independent of $k$.

Then the expected value of the second ball is given by $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n kp(k) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac 1n \cdot \frac 12 n(n+1) = \frac{n+1}2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I know why is the fact that the two draws are dependent?

Comment: Because the first pick influences the possibilities of the second pick. By definition, they are dependent. If you pick ball 3 the first time, you cannot possibly pick ball 3 the second since there is no replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much